# Is it possible to set property on controller based on a broadcasted event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following controller;

```
function RecruiterSignUpCtrl(AuthService) {
    // Store Users Sign Up Details as an object to POST.
    this.user = {
        name          : '',
        company       : '',
        email_address : '',
        password      : ''
     };

     // userSignUp is called on submit on the recruiter signup form.
     this.userSignUp = function(user) {
        // All heavy lifting is abstracted into AuthService.
        // Pass the role up from the controller.
        AuthService.signUp(user, 'recruiters');
     }

     this.signUpError = false;

  }
```

I want to change signUpError to true when a certain event is broadcast on the $rootScope. This event is broadcast from the AuthService.

Could someone confirm if this is possible?

B

Comment: It is possible, yes.  `AuthService` could fire an event using `$rootScope.$broadcast`.  And then the controller can handle the event using `$scope.$on`.

Comment: Yeah, that's currently what I am trying to do. I have the following, but this doesn't seem to work;

Comment: this.signUpError = function() {
      return false || $rootScope.on('AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed', function() {
        return true;
      });
    }

Comment: You should be using `$scope` in the controller, not `this`. And just change the value of `$scope.signUpError` inside the `$on` callback.

Comment: Thanks for this. Why should I use $scope instead of this? I apologise for the question, I am new to angular and it was a best practice I read about from Todd Motto so I ran with it

Comment: `$rootScope` is the top of a tree of `$scope`s.  `$broadcast` sends an event down through all the `$scope`s.

Answer (score 0):

please see here http://jsbin.com/mijum/1/edit

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){


  $scope.brodcast = function(){

    $rootScope.$broadcast('loginFailed', true);

  };

});

app.controller('RecruiterSignUpCtrl',function($scope){


  $scope.signUpError = false;

  $scope.$on("loginFailed", function (e, loggedIn) {



    $scope.signUpError = loggedIn;

  });


});
```